# Bootstrap pull-right class not working in <a> Tag

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Very basic question but I am stuck.

I have a button in table to edit but `class="pull-right"` is not working. Below is the code:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{article.id}}</td>
    <td>{{article.title}}</td>
    <td>{{article.author}}</td>
    <td>{{article.create_date}}</td>
    <td><a href="edit_article/{{article.id}}" class="btn btn-light pull-right">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image]

I want edit button be on right side.

This is not a duplicate. Please review it.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 , using SDN

Comment: It's now `float-right`, not `pull-right`